# What happens when two machines have same MAC address in a network?

Tags: network-programming

How the communication between two pc will be done and how the communication in the network will be done ? How do they bot coneect to the internet??
I m assuming may be one pc has spoofed another pc address.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how the machines' MAC address appear onto mac routing table.

https://superuser.com/questions/17696/what-happens-when-two-pcs-have-the-same-mac-adress

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. What eRIZ said.

Sometimes the machines will refuse to connect due collision OR one computer will connect before the another bouncing the other one of the network.

But yeah, it depends how they are configured.